# XNA triangle grid not drawn using DrawIndexedPrimitives

Tags: xna, monogame

I have just recently started working with Monogame (XNA). Now I had code that was drawing a grid using DrawUserIndexedPrimitives. However I read that it reloads the vertices in the GPU each draw, and I don't think that is going to cut it for me. Therefore I wanted to use DrawIndexedPrimitives instead.

However, when I made the switch, my pretty grid suddenly dissapeared. The question is thus: What did I do wrong using DrawIndexedPrimitives? The code within the draw method is given below:

```
game.GraphicsDevice.Indices = terrainIndexBuffer;
game.GraphicsDevice.SetVertexBuffer(terrainVertexBuffer);

game.GraphicsDevice.DrawIndexedPrimitives(PrimitiveType.TriangleList,
                                          0,
                                          0,
                                          terrainVertices.Length,
                                          0,
                                          triangleIndicesList.Length / 3);
// This worked VV
// game.GraphicsDevice.DrawUserIndexedPrimitives(PrimitiveType.TriangleList,
//                                               terrainVertices,
//                                               0,
//                                               terrainVertices.Length,
//                                               triangleIndicesList,
//                                               0,
//                                               triangleIndicesList.Length / 3);
```

Here `terrainVertices` is the list of vertices for the triangles, `triangleIndicesList` is a list representing the triangles (each three entries here refer to the vertices of one triangle).
Outside of the Draw method, I initialized the grid and index list as follows:

```
terrainVertexBuffer = new VertexBuffer(game.GraphicsDevice,
                                       typeof(VertexPosition),
                                       terrainVertices.Length,
                                       BufferUsage.None);

terrainIndexBuffer = new IndexBuffer(game.GraphicsDevice,
                                     IndexElementSize.SixteenBits,
                                     sizeof(short) * triangleIndicesList.Length,
                                     BufferUsage.None);

terrainVertexBuffer.SetData<VertexPosition>(terrainVertices);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that I forgot to initialize the terrainIndexBuffer with the array of indices.
So I added the line
`terrainIndexBuffer.SetData(triangleIndicesList);`